# How can i access the terminal remotely of raspberry pi board 3 through Port 80

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, remote-access, debian-stretch

Is there any way that I can get my raspberry pi boards terminal on the browser of another system connected in same network ; if any open source application is available to get remote access through port 80 that will also get the job done . All other Ports are closed , only available port is port 80 . The board is running Debian Version stretch . But I am not considering using Reverse Tunneling .

Comment: Run `sshd` on port 80 maybe? Run `jupyterlab` and allow `shell` notebooks maybe? Run `pigpiod` on port 80 maybe? Run a `mosh` server on port 80 maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does not seem possible, port 80 is the default port for http. Which is probably being used by a process that is serving a web app for the server.

At most you will be able to interact via REST APIs and/or SOAP but neither can give you remote access/control of the device.

Comment: ow .. can i configure nomachine application for port 80 atleast ; or team viewer for arm to work in port 80 ??

Comment: You mean to use a vnc/nomachine client? But is the vnc server or the remote desktop server running on your pi (since you'll connect with a client).? Even if it is running, is it communicating over port 80 - I'm assuming not.

Comment: @deepakdinesh If your question is answered, please vote and/or mark the answer as accepted :) https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work